# fibonacci sequence using assembly avr recursive

Tags: assembly, arduino, avr

Im trying to implementing a recursive function by pushing and popping intermediate values on the stack, also using recursion i need to implement Fibonacci numbers.

this is the assembly part everytime i run the program it give me that the sum of 10 is 0 and when i tried to changed it i got that the sum of 10 is 20 or 60.

in the "more:" function i tried to do the f(n-1) + f(n-2).

```
.text
.global recur

recursion:
 clr r18
 call recur
 mov r24, r18
 ret

 recur:   // simple summation recurrence.  We look at R24 and if it is > we set up things to recur

     CPI R24, 3
     brge more  // do some more

     // we are base case
     LDI R24, 1
     CLR R25
     ret

 more:
     dec R24
     push R24
     dec r24
     call recur
     add r18, r24
     // at this point R24 is the result, we need to add on what we pushed
     pop r24
     call recur
     ADD R18, R24
     clr r24
     CLR R25
     ret
```

this is the part written in C

```
// Cooper
// 2018
// recursion

// set up connect to AVR code

extern "C" { int recur(int);}

void setup() {


  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  int v;
  v=recur(10);
  Serial.begin(9600);

  Serial.print("The summation is ");
  Serial.println(v);



}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
   int v;
 v=recur(10);
  delay(1000);
  Serial.println(v);

}
```

Comment: don't validate assembly code by "running" it, use debugger to step over single instructions and validate the actual effect of single instructions against your plan/expectations.

Comment: I didn't run your exact code because I don't have the necessary tools for that. But I did rewrite your assembly code into x86-16 assembly, and if I call `recursion` with 10 as the input I get 55 as the output. Have you verfied that the problem isn't in your serial printing?

Comment: you're pushing r24, but what about r18? And at which point r24 become an result of the function It is only 1 or 0 before either or rets